# I'm working on a remote project that runs with .NET 4.5.1 and I want to locally run it on .NET 6.0, 7.0 or 8.0 - Linux Ubuntu - VS Code

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, version

My actual Linux OS is "22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
My VS Code version is: 1.85.1
My .NET SDKs versions installed are: 6.0.417 / 7.0.404 / 8.0.100
The question is:
Is it possible to locally run a project that was originally developed on .NET 4.5.1 in my current IDE? How may I proceed?
If not, is there a chance of installing .NET 4.5.1 in my Linux OS?

I've searched in .NET / fundamentals / "Manual Install" / "All .NET Core downloads" and the .NET version 4.5.1 is not even on "Out of support versions" list.
Thank you very much in advance for helping me.

Comment: .Net framework is windows-only. I'd say no chance of installing .NET 4.5.1 on Linux. Your project might run on Linux using a net core runtime - but probably you'll encounter problems. What should happen is a proper migration of the project to .Net core.